# Finding a complex bound

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\lvert z\rvert<R$ where $R\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that for $R>1$, $$\lvert z^2+1\rvert \ge R^2-1. $$

I'm not really sure what inequality will help..

Comment: Choose $R=2$ and $z=0$. Then the claim is $1 \geq 3$.

Comment: This is just the (reverse) triangle inequality. (But you probably want $|z|\ge R$ or $|z|=R$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If $|z| > R$**

$\displaystyle |z|>R \Rightarrow |z|^2>R^2 $

Thus by the triangle inequality we have that $\displaystyle |z^2+1|\geq |z^2|-1>R^2-1$

$$|z^2+1|>R^2-1$$

Comment: but $\lvert z\rvert < R$..

Comment: see if $R=3$ and $z=0 \Rightarrow 1>8$.